# Why don't these circles have different colors?

Tags: colors, lua, coronasdk

Why does:

```
local circle = {}

for i = 1, 15 do
    for j = 1, 15 do
        circle[i] = display.newCircle( 0 + (i*20), 100 + (j*20), 9)
        circle[i]:setFillColor(128, 128, i)
    end
end
```

not produce 255 circles with different colours? (if it is setting them all individually)

Comment: Should that not be `circle[i*j] =`? And the same idea for the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How could it produce 255 circles?

`i` only goes from 1 to 15. Therefore, `circle` will only contain 16 entries. I think what you're looking for is something more like this:

```
local circle = {}

for i = 1, 15 do
    for j = 1, 15 do
        circle[#circle + 1] = display.newCircle( 0 + (i*20), 100 + (j*20), 9)
        circle[#circle]:setFillColor(128, 128, (i * 16) + j)
    end
end
```

Comment: also 1 to 16 will do 16 circles. and 16*16 is 256.

Comment: @daurnimator: Yes, but 16*16 is larger than 255, which is not a valid color. It would make more sense to go from 0 to 15.